# mediaelement.js unload

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

Is there a way to unload mediaelement.js in the page? I have a video automatically playing in a slideshow with images and need to find a way to unload the video after it plays. I have an event listener that restarts the slideshow after the video ends, but when the video comes around again, it doesn't recognize the "success" function called when it originally loaded.